# Disable unit tests in a submodule using system property

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

In my scenario I want to disable running unit tests for some modules during multi-module build, e.g.

`mvn -Dmaven.test.skip.module1=true -Dmaven.test.skip.module2=true install`

In `module1` I can define a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>disable-unit-tests</id>

    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>maven.test.skip.module1</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</profile>
```

but when I try to generalize it and put to parent POM:

```
<profile>
    <id>disable-unit-tests</id>

    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>maven.test.skip.${project.artifactId}</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</profile>
```

it is not activated with above mentioned command.

What I am doing wrong? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Profile activation via properties cannot depend on properties, because properties are resolved later in the building of the default model.

In your case, the profile would be actived if the property 'maven.test.skip.${project.artifactId}' would be set.

Take a look at the following description: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-model-builder/

You need either to explicitly define your profile in all your submodules or use another plugin (either a self made) or gmaven/antrun to set a property depending on the presence of another one.

### Update

Example for the gmaven solution:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>createSkipProperty</id>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <source>
              if (properties["maven.test.skip.${project.artifactId}"])
                project.properties.setProperty("skip.this.module", "true")
            </source>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skip.this.module}</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This sets a skip.this.module property on the presence of maven.test.skip.${project.artifactId}. Advantage of this solution is, that you only need to define it once in your parent.

Comment: Could you please tell more details concerning gmaven/antrun approach? Late property setting won't activate a profile.

Comment: @dma_k: Correct, you cannot set the profile. However, you can define an additional property, which changes the skipTests configuration of the surefire plugin. I will update my answer with an example. By the way, it is always a good idea to let a profile only change properties and configure the plugin in the main part of the POM.